# Why can't 're' be used as a Sympy symbol?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I have a program that solves symbolic matrix equations using Sympy, and the variable names are user supplied. I've found that if 're' is used in any of the equations, I get an error. Any other symbol name, even 'Re', is fine. I've boiled it down to a quick test case. I'm using Python 3.7.4 and Sympy 1.5.1

```
import sympy

xe, Re, re = sympy.symbols('xe Re re')
# This is fine
eqn = sympy.sympify('(xe+3)*(Re+1)')
print("eqn=", eqn)
# This fails
eqn2 = sympy.sympify('(xe+3)*(re+1)')
print("eqn2=", eqn2)
```

Here's the program output with the error:

```
eqn= (Re + 1)*(xe + 3)
eqn2= Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/cache.py", line 94, in wrapper
    retval = cfunc(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 90, in sort_key
    args = expr.as_ordered_terms(order=order)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 1112, in as_ordered_terms
    terms, gens = self.as_terms()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 1142, in as_terms
    coeff, _term = term.as_coeff_Mul()
TypeError: as_coeff_Mul() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 8, in <module>
    print("eqn2=", eqn2)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py", line 414, in __str__
    return sstr(self, order=None)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/printing/str.py", line 871, in sstr
    s = p.doprint(expr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/printing/printer.py", line 249, in doprint
    return self._str(self._print(expr))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/printing/printer.py", line 287, in _print
    return getattr(self, printmethod)(expr, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/printing/str.py", line 277, in _print_Mul
    args = expr.as_ordered_factors()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/mul.py", line 1813, in as_ordered_factors
    cpart.sort(key=lambda expr: expr.sort_key(order=order))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/mul.py", line 1813, in <lambda>
    cpart.sort(key=lambda expr: expr.sort_key(order=order))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/cache.py", line 96, in wrapper
    retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 90, in sort_key
    args = expr.as_ordered_terms(order=order)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 1112, in as_ordered_terms
    terms, gens = self.as_terms()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 1142, in as_terms
    coeff, _term = term.as_coeff_Mul()
TypeError: as_coeff_Mul() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

In the field this program is intended for (electrical engineering, solving circuit equations), 're' is used very often, so I can't just not use it.

Comment: `sympy` already defines `re` as a function that returns the real part, https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#re

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sympyify` recognizes `re` as the [function](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#re) (and then it tells you you aren't using the function properly). You can give it your preferred meaning by passing a dictionary giving the preference to interpret `re` as a `Symbol('re')`:

```
>>> sympify('(xe+3)*(re+1)', {'re': Symbol('re')})
(re + 1)*(xe + 3)
```